# How to use lazy property loading with glassfish + toplink essentials

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, toplink-essentials

I have a query:

```
select p from Product p
```

Which gives me the results I expect, but one of the columns (let's call it `massiveDescription`) is big, and since I'm querying the full list of products I want to exclude it.

I added `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` to `getMassiveDescription()` but this made no difference (the generated sql still includes all columns).

I'm using glassfish pretty much out of the box, and it uses toplink essentials. I thought there might be something I had to do to configure the agent, so I tried adding `-javaagent:/path/to/toplink-essentials-agent.jar` in the JVM options through the glassfish web interface. Then I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/Synchronization
        at ...
```

So I figure I need to add `jta.jar` to the classpath suffix box in the glassfish web ui. That gives me a different exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/toplink/essentials/transaction/JTASynchronizationListener
        at oracle.toplink.essentials.transaction.JTATransactionController.<init>...
```

So now I'm chasing jars. I add `toplink-essentials.jar` to the classpath in the same way, but I still get the same exception.

I have a few questions:

- Is glassfish supposed to support bytecode enhancement for lazy property loading out of the box?
- If not, am I missing the correct way to configure it?
- I read that the "recommended" way to achieve this is using a project to select only part of the entity in the query. I like that better, but can't find any documentation on how to do it. Swapping `select p` for `select p.id, p.name, ...` gives me strange errors - but I was only guessing at the syntax anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out toplink essentials doesn't support this. Eclipselink does, so looks like I'm moving ORMs.

Comment: Draemon, switching from TLE to Eclipselink is super easy, and you won't regret it!

Comment: Not really. GF spat out some fairly confusing messages to begin with. Classloading and policy problems (some of which still aren't sorted). Of course GF3 doesn't have this problem, but I didn't want to switch.